# Update container image and retain volume data

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, prometheus

I am trying to update Prometheus container from 2.41 to 2.43 trying to maintain volume data but I cannot do that.
Here below the docker-compose used:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.43.1
    container_name: prometheus
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./prometheus/
        target: /etc/prometheus/
      - type: volume
        source: prometheus_data
        target: /prometheus
    command:
      - '--web.config.file=/etc/prometheus/web.yml'
      - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
      - '--storage.tsdb.path=/prometheus'
      - '--web.enable-lifecycle'
volumes:
  prometheus_data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /monitor-data/prometheus
```

Every time I change the tag image, my volume (prometheus_data) will be empty. Is there a way to retain the data?

Comment: Is there data in the host `/monitor-data/prometheus` directory?  Is the `/prometheus` directory inside the container correct?  Are you writing any actual code here, or just trying to deploy and configure Prometheus?

Comment: Yes, there are data into /monitor-data/prometheus and /prometheus is inside.
My Prometheus is working properly, but when I try to update the version I lose data contained into /monitor-data/prometheus

Comment: This question is very clearly off-topic. See the description of [tag:docker] on what docker questions are on-topic here.

Comment: If you run a completely different image, e.g. busybox, mounting prometheus_data, is the content being deleted? If not, the issue is with the prometheus image itself, or your configuration of that image.